# Elasticsearch Query sorted by field in specific order

Tags: elasticsearch

I work with elasticsearch 2.2

I have some documents indexed like that:

```
{     
  "id": 2116,
  "brand": "The Brand 1",
  "reference": "OI444",
  "supplier": "My supplier 1"
},
{     
  "id": 2118,
  "brand": "The Brand",
  "reference": "OI44488",
  "supplier": "My supplier"
}
```

how i can request the index to get a query sorted by an id list, this query work, but return the result in other order.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "ids": {
          "values": [
            2118, 2116
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, my ids list can be random like 216,105,208 and i need this order be respected in resultset

Answer (score 1):

- Field which you use should be not analyzed in mapping
- Add sort

Query

```
POST c1_2/Test/_search/
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "doc['id'] != null ? sortOrder.indexOf(doc['id'].value.toInteger()) : 0",
        "type": "number",
        "params": {
          "sortOrder": [
            2116,
            211
          ]
        },
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    "_score"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "brand": [
              "The"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [
              2118,
              2116,
              211
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank, but in my case, my ids list can be random like 216,105,208 and i need this order be respected,

Comment: yes but that ids are in document so why it should matter? you filter on ids

Comment: you have in your document field "id": "2116" so you are telling ES sort me on this field

Comment: Exemple for old version of elastic http://damienalexandre.fr/post/elasticsearch-ids-query-order

Comment: Its when you want to sort by _id of document, from your example i understood that you document has "id" field which is the same as _id (some times they are different if use autogenerate). So if you sort by _id it wont work if you use id it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104894/discussion-between-volodymyr-bilyachat-and-bourvill).